# i have a problem with list slicing in python

Tags: python, list, slice

In example1, L[0:2:1] can assign by [99,99,99,99,99]

```
# example1:
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[0:2:1] = [99,99,99,99,99]
print(L)

#output: [99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

but example2, L[-1:-2:-1] can't assign by [99,99,99,99,99]

```
# example2:
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[-1:-2:-1] = [99,99,99,99,99]
print(L)

#ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 5 to extended slice of size 1
```

I don't understand why  L[-1:-2:-1] can't assign by [99,99,99,99,99]

Answer (score 0):

Assigning values using slicing works with both positive and negative numbers. But you need to assign the correct length of sequence for the number of items produced by the slice:

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[1:5:2] = [99, 99]
print(L)   # [0, 99, 2, 99, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[1:5:2] = [99, 99, 99]  # ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 3 to extended slice of size 2
```

Or with negative:

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[-2:-4:-1] = [99, 99]
print(L)   # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99, 99, 9]
L[-2:-4:-1] = [99, 99, 99]  # ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 3 to extended slice of size 2
```

The exception to that rule is when the slice step is 1 (or omitted as 1 is the default). Then the matched slice is removed and replaced with whatever is assigned to it.

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[1:9] = [99]
print(L)  # [0, 99, 9]
```

Comment: Can you explain to me about "when the slice step is 1 (or omitted as 1 is the default). Then the matched slice is removed and replaced with whatever is assigned to it.". Is it working due to a feature in python or is it based on some principle

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation for this but I assume it was a feature to make slice assignments more powerful and flexible. When the step is 1 it's easy for python to interpret the meaning of setting a different length sequence (replace everything between two indices). But it's harder to implement a consistent and predictable replacement when the step is not 1.

Answer (score 0):

In you scond example, `L[-1:-2:-1]` refers to a slice that starts at index -1 and ends at index -2 with a step of -1, which means that it selects the last element of the list. Therefore, the slice `L[-1:-2:-1]` contains only one element.

To assign the value `[99,99,99,99,99]` to the last element of the list, you can use `L[-1:]` instead of `L[-1:-2:-1]`.

```
L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
L[-1:] = [99,99,99,99,99]
print(L)
```

which returns:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99]
```